What is "What *is*."?
I was reading an essay by philosopher Jiddu Krishnamurti when I ran into these sentences:

“Understanding comes through being aware of what is. To know exactly
what is, the real, the actual, without interpreting it, without
condemning or justifying it, is, surely, the beginning of wisdom. ”

(Excerpt from The First and Last Freedom, Jiddu Krishnamurti)
What does he exactly mean by "what is"? I have heard of this phrase before, but I always disliked it, since it sounded very hand-wavy and grammatically incorrect/incomplete. When I read it, I say in my head, "what comes after is?" I do not even have a rough idea of what he means here, since I cannot explain with my own words. Perhaps I am not equipped with a cultural context that would have allowed me to extrapolate.

A simplistic answer is that this is the existential sense of 'be' (ie 'be' = 'is in the physical world') (perhaps including abstracts that can be sensed, like heat, pain, joy). A satisfactory answer belongs on Philosophy.SE.

The clause that troubles you is in fact a rhetorical device, designed to bring you up short to emphasise the point being made.  'Never mind," he is saying, what might justifies or explains some thing or event: focus on the fact or thing itself:  on what is.  The sentence that follows it, in apposition to it, makes this clear.  It is not uncommon for thinkers to express themselves in puzzling oracular ways.  Wittgenstein's famous Tractatus logico-philosophicus began "The world is everything that is the case. It is made of facts not of things."

Grammatically, it seems to follow the trails of "I think, therefore I am".

"It depends on what the meaning of is is."
--American philosopher, Bill Clinton

It’s a perfectly natural and grammatical usage. The OED’s first entry (of entries arranged chronologically by appearance in the language) for is is:

is verb
I. Without required complement: to have or take place in the world of fact, to exist, occur, happen.
I.1.a. To have place in the objective universe or realm of fact, to exist; (spec. of God, etc.) to exist independently of other
beings. Also: to exist in life, to live. Now literary. Old
English– [selected attestations] 1587
  All things that are, or euer were, or shall hereafter bee. —Sir
P. Sidney & A. Golding, translation of P. de Mornay, Trewnesse of
Christian Religion iii. 29 1827   God is, nay
alone is. —T. Carlyle in Edinburgh Review October 347
1961   When all things began, the Word already was.
—Bible (New English) John i. 1 Source: Oxford
English Dictionary (login required)

So:

Understanding comes through being aware of what [has place in the objective universe].


Let us not forget the 1969 Led Zepplin song "What is and what should never be"

I believe another common (but old) usage would be something like "She is no more".

@CWC — Yes, all in there under I.1.a.... 1697 Troy is no more, and Ilium was a Town! 1762 The parting Ship that instant is no more. 2004 After 58 years the BBC's Letter from America, the world's longest-running speech radio programme, is no more.

Grammatically, there is nothing special about this phrasing. Any intransitive verb could replace 'is', and 'what' is a relative pronoun replacing the subject of the relative clause.

Jiddu knows what is.


Jiddu knows who remains.


Jiddu knows what jumps.

'is' is intransitive here, though usually as a copulative, expects a following subject. This may be your intuition about what comes after 'is'.
In

I am what I am.

the first 'am' has an following phrase, what I am'. The second one doesn't need or expect anything to follow.
Since 'is' is one of the most common words (in almost any language that uses copulatives (some don't)), it is very general, has lots of nuances in meaning in many different contexts, and therefore without further explanation is very vague.
In usual philosophical style, concepts which are new and abstruse are often explained with vague, non-specific vocabulary in an almost mystical way, striving to get the reader to fill in the opaque gaps. "What does 'is' mean? What is 'real', or 'actual', or 'wisdom'? The author thinks they know and being vague gives them a lot of freedom to be assumed to be profound. Or maybe he just grew up in a household where some parent was 'away for work' but nobody ever said anything and tiptoed around it, being all weird, and as a child he couldn't figure out why, and it turned out the dad was in prison. Why? Oh that's a whole nother story... that's what's really real.
Anyway, sometimes philosopher's get carried away. Sometimes they make up new words for existing concepts and make them obscure, and sometimes they use old words in totally new ways to make them obscure.
But without the full context of Krishnamourti's text, it is difficult to figure out exactly what 'is' means for him (if it is indeed different from the usual everyday 'is').

In “I am what I am”, the second am does expect and have something that follows – but that something is the subject complement which has fused with its own antecedent into a single what. ‘Unfusing’ them into that which yields, “I am that which I am”, where the underlying structure is more transparently Iᵢ am thatₓ [whichₓ Iᵢ am _xₓ] (with the co-indexed gap at the end).

Oops, an x too much in that comment. The end should read Iᵢ am thatₓ whichₓ Iᵢ am _ₓ.

I take it very literally. Like in "A Rose for Emily," what seems proud and aloof, a relic of a bygone era…IS actually a murderer lying with the corpse, from spinsterhood to death, or however long it was…becomes what is, over time, Southern Gothic. If she just slept with him one or two times while he was still fresh, that's hardly Southern Gothic, more like plain ole necro-napping. Some things evolve into terror. Who can say what IS at any given time? IDK.

This is the existential "is" = exists

OED: to be (v.)
I. Without required complement: to have or take place in the world
of fact, to exist, occur, happen.
I.1.a. To have place in the objective universe or realm of fact, to exist; (spec. of God, etc.) to exist independently of other beings.
Also: to exist in life, to live. Now literary.
the powers that be: see power n.1 II.8b.
to be no more: see no more adv. C.1c.
1961 When all things began, the Word already was. Bible (New English)
John i. 1
2004 After 58 years the BBC's Letter from America, the world's
longest-running speech radio programme, is no more. Independent 3
March 10/1


English is not my first language so please bear with me. However I think I can try to attempt an essence of the communication. Does following paraphrasing help?

Understanding 'X' comes through being aware of what is 'X'. To know exactly what is 'X', the real 'X', the actual 'X',......... ==> 'is', the 'beginning' 'of wisdom'.
Where, 'X' = any "thing" or non "thing"

What does "is" signify => he seems to be referring to a different "is knowledge" than what philosophy allows. According to Jiddu is of any X, can be referred to something that comes without interpreting X, without condemning X or justifying X and so on. Other way to say the same thing would be 'it refers to something that comes without categorizing'.

Now in Non-Indian culture where Jiddu is easily categorized as a philosopher, this gets tricky. Since how can one know anything without differentiating it from something else. Any idea is typically conceptualized by differentiating it with other similar ones. Thus difference is at the core of any non-Indian 'knowledge of is'. Focus is the question 'what' rather than 'how' and 'why' here. I think Jiddu says that eventually 'the question what' is not only a necessary question 'to be aware of any knowledge' but 'the only sufficient question'.

Now, let's for a moment try this out. I know you exist to begin with. The very word existence signifies something that stands out etymologically. Signifying 1. my focus on you, and 2. my categorization and nothing really about you per se. Typically, for I to know you (a non-thing {once a non thing example is clear, things are automatically become understandable}), I would say you are western, white, sensible, thinking and so on..., depending on what I think of you. This will evolve as we interact more and more without any end. Till infinity. As I have no means to know you other than categorizing you. There is no means with me to enter your mind for example. Thus even after infinity there will be a gap in what you is and what I think you is.

Why the above difference of what you is and what I think you is persists? Jiddu is saying (not thinking and saying, but just saying), it is because of 2 problems: A. difference at the root of knowledge, loosely can be translated as fallacy in epistemology and B. "Thinking {cogito, ergo sum' instead of 'Being Aware' when understanding is of any X.

I am sure he explicates both A and B in the book or series of other talks he has given. You will have to be patient as it is not easy to simulate alternative knowledge system when deep entrenched inside your current knowledge system.

On words real, actual used by Jiddu:-  I think they are not used in philosophical point of view say like used by Roy Bhaskar in his Critical Realism. This is also previously mentioned in answer by Mitch. I think they are used to simply emphasize the significance of "is". This may be due to difficulty felt by him to communicate his knowledge system to people following other knowledge system, precisely. I also think this must be a part of talk rather a written script by him which explains use of these words for emphasizing.

I think 'if one keeps' these two problems and the epistemological solution of "Being Aware" 'in mind and starts to understand the world' then it will be according to Jiddu, a 'beginning of Wisdom'.


Now the word like 'awareness' have different meaning as well but that will be clear from his talks. Also how "being aware" can help come up with knowledge of any X must have been explicated as well. You will, over time also recognize that 'Jiddu's knowledge of is'  is also beyond linguistic knowledge, which will explain how he tackles the problem of difference at root of knowledge. You will have to go through these talks in many iterations after some finite life experience interval. Very intently each time. That way, same text will yield more and more clarity, this has been my experience with Jiddu. Hope this helps to proceed with English language use by Jiddu.

This site is devoted to English language and usage; the question belongs to this site only in so far as it is about the use of is in the passage, and this has been adequately explained in the other answers. Overall interpretation of the substance of some text is outside the scope of this site.
